# Remove bottom border radius from the input when the suggestions are open

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am using this autocomplete plugin: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Using the onSearchComplete to add class to the input to remove the border radius but I'm having issues removing this class when its selected or hidden.

```
var $input = $('input[name=search]');
$input.autocomplete({
    onSearchStart : function(){ $input.addClass('autocomplete-loading') },
    onSearchComplete : function(){ $input.removeClass('autocomplete-loading').addClass('autocomplete-open') }
});
```

Looking at the [options](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) dont think there is a way to extend onClose/etc so looking at the source I need to modify the hide: function but how can I select the input from inside this plugin?

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Fbdhy

Comment: It would help if you posed a demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onSelect` callback to remove class:

```
$input.autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: 'search.json',
    onSearchStart: function() {
        $(this).addClass('autocomplete-loading')
    },
    onSearchComplete: function() {
        $(this).removeClass('autocomplete-loading').addClass('autocomplete-open')
    },
    onSelect: function() {
        $(this).removeClass('autocomplete-loading autocomplete-open');
    },
    onHide : function() {
        $(this).removeClass('autocomplete-loading autocomplete-open');
    }
});
```

**UPD**. Unfortunately there is no callback function for situation when dropdown is closed using click outside or with Escape key. In this case you can simply add this method yourself by extending `Autocomplete.prototype.hide` method which is called in this case:

```
(function(original) {
    $.Autocomplete.prototype.hide = function() {
        this.options.onHide && this.options.onHide.call(this.element, this.options.params);
        original.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})($.Autocomplete.prototype.hide);
```

Also inside callback `this` points to the same input element, so you can use `$(this)`.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/YQwpljoZnJbLpQzwWpxV?p=preview

Comment: Sorry I was just creating a demo with this. The problem is that it will only remove the class open if you select a suggestion, not if you focus away

Comment: Very nice, never knew you could extend a function like that.

Comment: Yes, this is applying mixing pattern on object prototype. Cool thing, because you don't have to mess with library source code to make some tweaks. Basically you don't change anything about original library code, just wrap it with your own function.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use hide: 
you can select item using "this"

```
hide: function () {
        var input = this;
        input.visible = false; //for hiding

        $(input).removeClass('abc').addClass('cba');
    }
```

if you want to use onSearchComplete: i guess you can retrieve 3 elements from it

```
onSearchComplete: function(element, q, suggestions) {
                     //check element is the input
                     $(element).removeClass('abc').addClass('cba');
                }
```